# How to assign a class type to arraylist of type Any?

Tags: android

I have lateinit arraylist of type Any in service. The scenario I've is that lists of three different types are coming from three different fragments. I have to assign it a type of my choice based on intent. How can I do the same? or how can I meet my required scenario which is how to assign different types to a same arraylist based on type of list received

Comment: Please add an [mcve]. Code says more than a thousand words.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like (if all items are the same within a list)

```
if(list[0] is Subtype1)
val specificList = list.map{item -> item as Subtype1}
```

specificList should then have type `List<Subtype1>`

I didn't test this and you need to handle edge cases like empty lists, maybe try/catch for the map etc but this should be a start. you can also use a `when` instead of if, if you need to switch between multiple types